# Implicit constructor arguments

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I always thought that implicit constructor in C++ could only be a constructor with only one argument. For example:

```
class Foo1
{
   Foo(int); // This could be an implicit constructor
};
```

But is the following code right:

```
class Foo2
{
    Foo2(int, int=0);  // Would compiler use this as an implicit constructor?
}
```

I can do this:

```
Foo1 obj;
...
obj = 5;
```

What about `Foo2`?

Comment: Explicit constructor has a different meaning. What you are talking is about constructor with default arguments.

Comment: @mahesh I know the meaning of explicit constructors and question is a question :) Okay, I will fill it with an example.

Comment: None of those are explicit constructors--they're not marked with `explicit` keyword. Do you mean *implicit* constructor? If so, yes, constructors can be invoked implicitly if the n+1 parameters are assigned default arguments.

Comment: How is `obj = 5;` is a valid statement ? Am I missing anything here ?

Comment: @cody-gray Yep, thanks. I've already changed that. You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @mahesh If constructor has 1 argument and doesn't have `explicit` keyword before declaration that statement is valid.

Comment: ¤ The accepted solution (as I'm writing this) misses the point. In short, the Holy C++11 Standard's §12.1/5 defines a default constructor as one that can be *called* without any actual arguments, and similarly §13.3.1.4 effectively defines an implicitly callable converting constructor as one that can be called with one argument and that is not (§12.3.1/1) declared `explicit`. That's about it. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, *any* constructor can be marked `explicit`. How many arguments it has is irrelevant.

With that out of the way, you just now need to understand what `explicit` really means. It just means that the only way that constructor can be called is when you *explicitly* specify the class name:

```
struct foo
{
    foo(int){}
    explicit foo(double){}
};

void bar(foo){}

bar(5); // okay, calls foo(int) to construct the foo
bar(3.14); // error, cannot call foo(double) because foo was not explicitly used
bar(foo(3.14)); // okay, calls foo(double) to construct the foo
```

The reason we don't mark multiple-argument constructors explicit is because it's useless. Given:

```
struct baz
{
    baz(int, int, int);
};
```

How else can you call that constructor other than saying `baz` anyway? (As in `baz(1, 2, 3)`.)†

In your example, `explicit` would be sensible because you *could* call that constructor with only one argument. What you actually do only depends on if you feel it should be implicitly convertible or not.

---

†This is disregarding C++11 initializer lists. In C++11, I think you could say:

```
void qaz(baz) {}

qaz({1, 2, 3});
```

And manage to get an implicit conversion to a multiple-argument constructor, but I don't know enough about initializer-lists to make a meaningful comment except as a footnote.

Comment: I always mark all constructors `explicit`, for two reasons: symmetry, and the chance that someday some programmer might decide that all but the first argument could use some default value, and add it. (Except for ctors that I really *want* to do implicit conversions of course, which I almost never do)

Comment: @PaulGroke: Making all constructors `explicit` is not needed. Only those which take one argument, is what I think need to be marked `explicit`.

Comment: @Nawaz: I know that it's not needed, and quite frankly I'm not sure how you could ever misinterpret my comment to come to the conclusion that I wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking, then the answer is yes.

To be more specific, essentially *any* ctor that can be invoked with only one argument can and will be used for implicit conversions. To prevent that, such a ctor can be marked `explicit`. That applies equally to a ctor that only takes one argument, or one that *can* take more than one argument, but supplies default values for the other arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing EXplicit and IMplicit here. What you're talking about are conversion constructors. An explicit constructor is just the opposite: one that can *not* be used for (implicit) conversions.

And to answer your question: yes, `Foo2(int, int=0)` is a conversion constructor that enables implicit conversion like in `obj = 5`, becaust it can be called with one `int` argument.

The same goes for default constructors: if you add a default value for the first parameter as well, it will additionally become the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably meant is *implicit* constructors, not *explicit*.

Anyway, you cannot do this (as opposed to what you think you can):

```
Foo1 obj; //this line will not compile as it takes one argument!
obj = 5;
```

I'm sure you've not compiled your code before saying you can do this.

However, if you meant this,

```
Foo1 obj(10); //OK now
obj = 5;
```

Then yes, you can.

Now how about `Foo2`? Well, [you can do so](http://ideone.com/0U0i3) in case of `Foo2` as well:

```
Foo2 foo(10);
foo = 5;
```